# ViewController with locked orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation-changes

I am having issues with the following situation:

ViewController A should be locked on landscape (left or right). The setup for VC A is the following:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

ViewController B should be locked on portrait. Its setup is the following:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

There is no navigation controller, or tab bar. It is just a regular view controller and then on a button press I go from ViewController A to ViewController B with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB" sender:self];
```

Everything is fine so far. But when I dismiss ViewController B then ViewController A shows up on portrait. This is how I dismiss VC B:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Another problem is: when I am on ViewController B and it is OK on portrait, then I start to quickly rotate my device from portrait to landscape several times and it rotates to landscape at some point despite the orientation rules above. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidAppear:` try using this method to rotate to your desired orientation, in case the orientation is wrong at the load of the controller:

```
NSNumber *value = @(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); // Or whatever else orientation you need.
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Also redefine your `shouldAutorotate` method like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    // Change the YES or NO order depending on your viewController.
    return [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ? YES : NO;
}
```

And implement this method as well:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // Or whatever orientation you need in this viewController.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. At first it seems to work - when I go to B then back A it really enforces landscape on A. But then, the second time I do this to problem happens again - A appears wrongly on portrait. It seems like a pattern, one time it works the next it doesn't. I am sure there is an explanation but I am failing to find it.